# Android Programming - locking application

Tags: android, locking

Hi all u geeks out there... i'm a novice in Android programming though had tried my hand on blackberry...

currently i was asked 4 the possibility of making an application which can control access to other applications on Android... I mean something like asking password everytime some selected apps are opened... My question is.. "is it possible to make an application which does something like this"... Any feedback will be appreciated.. Thanx in advance guys...

Comment: Sorry, @Javadid, I didn't realise how important this was. I'll get right on it :-) No, seriously, sit back and relax, take a number and wait. Not *every* question is answered in the first ten minutes (just 99% of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create an SDK application as you describe. If you can do that, then malware can do that, holding a user's phone hostage.

As tm1brt indicates, you may be able to do this via your own custom firmware and modifications to the Android OS, but then that will only affect your phones (personal ones or ones you are manufacturing). And modifying the Android OS is not trivial.

Comment: thanx commonsware.com(don know ur real name!)... great reply.. i too thought bout it but guess clients have wierd imaginations... :)

Comment: If I understand well the problem, then you can find applications in Android Market that do this thing: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smartlockfree&feature=search_result. So it's not impossible. I'm also interested in mechanism used here, so any comment is appreciatied.

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to do this by modifying the OS.
Or perhaps writing a new home screen.

Comment: Not even a new home screen, since the user can always go back to the original home screen.

Comment: Thanx tm1rbrt... but i guess its not goin to work out... thanx anyways.. ur contribution has really helped me a lot... guess though im knew here... i'll be a frequent contributor 4m now on... thanx 2 u all...

Comment: commonsware.com is wrong. You can replace the original home screen with a custom one.

Comment: Not this kind a program is what JaVadid asked for ? http://www.appbrain.com/app/app-protector-pro/com.carrotapp.protectpronew